# Ιf $\mathbb{E}(e^X)<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(e^{-X})<\infty,$ then $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Ιf $X$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}(e^X)<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(e^{-X})<\infty,$ then $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$.

*Attempt.* Since $e^x\geqslant x+1,$ we get
$e^X\geqslant X+1$ and $e^{-X}\geqslant 1-x$, so $1-e^{-X}\leqslant X\leqslant 1+e^X$. Therefore $ |X|\leqslant \max\{1+e^X,|1-e^{-X}|\}$. But what be said about $\mathbb{E}|1-e^{-X}|$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following inequality might be helpful: $$|x| \leq e^{|x|} \leq e^x + e^{-x} \qquad\text{for}\quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Apply triangle inequality to you result $|X|\leq|1-e^{-X}|$ then you might see how it can be completed.